# Condition on join tables - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

My models:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :business

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
```

I want to get the Reviews for businesses under a certain category:

```
Review.joins(:business => :categories).where(:business => {:categories => [1,2,3,4]})
```

The resulting query:

```
SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" INNER JOIN 
"businesses" ON "businesses"."id" = "reviews"."business_id" INNER JOIN 
"businesses_categories" ON "businesses_categories"."business_id" = "businesses"."id" 
INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "businesses_categories"."category_id" 
WHERE "business"."categories" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry 
for table "business"
LINE 1: ...id" = "businesses_categories"."category_id" WHERE "business"...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
Review.joins(:business => :categories).where( :categories => { :id => [1,2,3,4] } )
```

Comment: You're very welcome! The thing is, inside an AR where clause when you use a hash, it takes the key to be the table and the key/s inside the value to be the columns. So :businesses =? { :categories => 1 } translates to "where businesses.categories = 1". Also, you use array nesting for join - you don't need to use it for where, order, group, etc... It is used for joins to actually nest the inner joins on each other, but once that is done, all the joined tables are directly accessible thru their name in the rest of the query.